# Deleting records does not affect unused space in data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 database where one table had around 485 million records.  After deleting around 120 million records, the amount of free space in the data file did not change.  I figured I should have around 80GB more unused space.  Data gets loaded into the table daily and I want to keep the data file from auto growing and using up more disk space.  I did rebuild the only index on the table after the delete, but that didn't help.  Is there a reason I am not seeing more space available in the data file?

Comment: Is the table a heap? You say you rebuilt the "only index" - was it clustered or non-clustered?

Comment: That was it!  I did not realize that not having a clustered index would cause this.  The table rebuild freed up a lot of space in the file.  It did use a lot of space and cause several auto grows while running, so anyone running a table rebuild will want to make sure they have plenty of drive space if the table is large.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that fixed it for you!